# Calculating same equation but using different values in the parameters

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, modeling

So I have this equation:

eq <- a*b*X*d*(C/FB)*e

Where all letters above represent constants, but X, C, and FB can take different values:

- X can be 0.8 or 0.1
- C can be 10, 100 or 250
- FB can be 0.2 or 0.8

In total, there are 2 x 3 x 2 = 12 possible combinations of these 3 variables, meaning 12 ways to solve this equation.

My question is, how can I write the code to for R to solve equation 'eq' for all 12 possible combinations of X, C, and FB?

Thank you so much for your help.

I suspect this has something to do with for loops, but I am new to R and I'm still not familiar with how these work.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how you could do this

```
equation <- 
  function(a,b,c,d){
  a + b*c^d
  }

a <- 1
b <- c(1,2)
c <- 1:3
d <- 10

library(dplyr)

expand.grid(a = a,b = b,c = c,d = d) %>% 
  mutate(y = equation(a,b,c,d))

  a b c  d      y
1 1 1 1 10      2
2 1 2 1 10      3
3 1 1 2 10   1025
4 1 2 2 10   2049
5 1 1 3 10  59050
6 1 2 3 10 118099
```